# Why is my density graph different from base R when i'm using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

So as you can see in the uploaded pictures my range of my density bars is different dependent on the model I use (Base R or ggplot2) 
e.g for the blue bars on 115 the bar in ggplot2 plummet but it doesn't when I use Base R.

I already tried this link (inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/density) but I'm new to R and didn't find the solution.

**Base R**

```
Immature2=subset(dataHistogram2, Sex=='I')
Female2=subset(dataHistogram2, Sex=='F')
Male2=subset(dataHistogram2, Sex=='M')

hist(Immature2$Diameter, prob=TRUE ,breaks= seq(55,125, by=5), ylim=c(0,0.05), xlim=c(55,125), col=rgb(0,1,0,1/2), main="", xlab= "Diameter", ylab="Densiteit")
hist(Female2$Diameter, prob=TRUE, add=TRUE, breaks= seq(55,125, by=5), col=rgb(1,0,0,1/2))
hist(Male2$Diameter, prob= T,breaks=seq(55,125, by=5), add=T, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/2)) 

x=seq(55,125,0.01)
curveImmature2<-curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Immature2$Diam), sd=sd(Immature2$Diam)), add= TRUE, col=rgb(0,1,0,1/2), lwd=2)
curveFemale2 <- curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Female2$Diam), sd=sd(Female2$Diam)), add= TRUE, col= rgb(1,0,0,1/2), lwd=2)
curveMale2 <- curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(Male2$Diam), sd=sd(Male2$Diam)), add= TRUE, col=rgb(0,0,1,1/2), lwd=2)
```

[image]

**GGplot2**

```
ggplot(dataHistogram2, aes(x=Diameter)) + 
             geom_histogram(binwidth=5, aes(y=..density.., colour=Sex, fill= Sex), position="identity", alpha=0.5)+xlim(55,125) + 
             stat_function(fun=dnorm, colour = "green", args=list(mean=mean(Immature2$Diameter), sd=sd(Immature2$Diameter)))  + 
             stat_function(fun=dnorm, colour = "red", args=list(mean=mean(Female2$Diameter), sd=sd(Female2$Diameter)))  + 
             stat_function(fun=dnorm, colour = "blue", args=list(mean=mean(Male2$Diameter), sd=sd(Male2$Diameter)))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the range has changed, it's probably just different binning strategies.

Comment: try adding `right = TRUE` to `geom_histogram()`

Comment: yes , bins are different as joran said